# Solving ODE's with GPU in python

Tags: python, numpy, gpu, ode

i have a final project in physics in which i should numerically solve some 4D ODE system and show its chaotic properties by visualaizing how all the initial conditions evolve over time. i wanted to plot it like the video -
https://youtu.be/n7JK4Ht8k8M?t=106
but when trying to run the code with grid of 100x100 it is just taking very long time, and i can't give up on high resulution beacuse i have to show the fractal behvior of the system.
i was looking for hours of how to solve this using my gpu (rtx 3070) but found almost nothing related to ODE'S using python. is there any way to approach this?
thanks!

```
#%% Import Packages
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos , sin
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgb
import math
#%% Define Simulation parameters
TIME_FINAL = 10
FRAME_NUM = 300
MAP_RES = 1000
#%% Define Control Parameters
g = 9.8
l = 1
m = 1
#%% Define the ODE System 

# Define a time axis (number of frames)
t = np.linspace(0, TIME_FINAL, FRAME_NUM)

# Define our model (Contains the equations of motion for our system)
def model(cords , t):
    th1 , th2 , p1 , p2 = cords
    th1_dot = 6/(m*l**2) * ((2*p1 - 3*cos(th1-th2)*p2) / (16 - 9*(cos(th1 -th2))**2))
    th2_dot = 6/(m*l**2) * ((8*p2 - 3*cos(th1-th2)*p1) / (16 - 9*(cos(th1 -th2))**2))
    p1_dot = -0.5*m*l**2 * (th1_dot*th2_dot*sin(th1-th2) + 3*(g/l)*sin(th1))
    p2_dot = -0.5*m*l**2 * (-th1_dot*th2_dot*sin(th1-th2) + (g/l)*sin(th1))
    return [th1_dot , th2_dot , p1_dot , p2_dot]
    
#%% First Impression

init0 = np.array([1.3 , 0.7 , 0 , 0]) # Adjust the values to observe chaotic behivior
th1 , th2 , p1 , p2 = odeint(model,init0 ,t).T

plt.figure(dpi = 300)
plt.plot(t, th1 , label = r"$\theta1$", linewidth = 1)
plt.plot(t, th2 , label = r"$\theta2$", linewidth = 1)
plt.grid("on")
plt.legend()
plt.title(fr"$\theta1$ and $\theta2$ ({init0})")   
    
#%% Constructing an initial sub phase-space

# Define the ranges for theta and p_theta coordinates
theta1_range = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, MAP_RES)  
theta2_range = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, MAP_RES)
# Create a mesh grid of theta1 and theta2 values
theta1_grid, theta2_grid = np.meshgrid(theta1_range, theta2_range)

# %% Calculating the Sub Phase Space Progression Over Time
p1_i = 0
p2_i = 0
i = 0
phase_space = []
for (theta , phi) in zip(np.ravel(theta1_grid), np.ravel(theta2_grid)) :
    initial_condition = [theta , phi ,p1_i , p2_i]
    th1 , th2 , _ , __ = odeint(model,initial_condition ,t).T
    phase_space.append((th1,th2))
    i = i + 1
    print(f"Completed {i}/{theta1_grid.size}")

#%% Generating the Color map from the sub phase space data

def rad2rgb(theta, phi, radius = 127):
            return [math.floor(radius + radius * np.cos(phi) * np.sin(theta)),
                    math.floor(radius + radius * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)),
                    math.floor(radius + radius * np.cos(theta))]
           
color_maps = []
for i in range(t.size) :
 rgb_colors = np.array([rad2rgb(phase[0][i], phase[1][i]) for phase in phase_space])
 rgb_colors = rgb_colors.reshape(theta1_grid.shape[0], theta1_grid.shape[1], 3)
 color_maps.append(rgb_colors)   
#%% Animating the Phase Space and saving into .GIF file
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def update(frame):
    ax.clear()
    ax.imshow(color_maps[frame], origin='lower', extent=(0, 2*np.pi, 0, 2*np.pi), aspect='auto')
    ax.set_xlabel(r'$\theta1$')
    ax.set_ylabel(r'$\theta2$')
    ax.set_title(r'Color Map in $(\theta1 , \theta2)$ Space')


anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames= len(color_maps), interval=50)
#anim.save('Fractal.gif', writer='pillow', fps=60, dpi=150)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Generic advice would be to profile your script and see what makes it slow ([doc1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) and [doc2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-do-i-profile-a-python-script)). Also, where exactly are you using GPU in your code?

Comment: The reason why you wont find much is that the computationally intensive ODE problems most people care about are different from what you try to do (which is not saying that what you are aiming at is wrong). People either care about PDEs (which lead to high-dimensional ODEs with a regular structure which are [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) and thus benefit from GPUs) or high-dimensional ODEs without a regular structure (which are MIMD and thus do not benefit from GPUs). You have lots of initial conditions for the same low-dimensional ODE, which is SIMD. […]

Comment: […] Thus, you can benefit from GPUs, but I suggest that you first vectorise your problem at all and see whether this is satisfyingly fast. In brief: Handle all initial conditions simultaneously, instead one by one. Create a system of 4×100×100 ODEs (where only groups of four ODEs interact) and run it with your 100×100 sets of initial conditions. Using NumPy, all of this can be efficiently run on arrays. The downside of this is that the step-size adaption is the same for all trajectories, but that also applies to a GPU solution and you will probably require finer steps for your video anyway.